# Java: Found long, required int

Tags: java, casting, int, long-integer

I'm trying to sort some arrays in Java using this line:

```
a = sortFacade.sort(2, false, a);
```

where 'a' is an already initialised int array. When I try to compile it, I'm told that the 2 is a long, not an int. I've tried casting it with (int)2 with no luck.

I also tried the line

```
sortFacade.sort(2, false, a);
```

and the code compiles.

does anyone know a fix to this?

Edit: Here's the message I get in Terminal:

```
Experimenter.java:146: incompatible types
found   : long
required: int[]
        a = sortFacade.sort(2, false, a);
                           ^
```

This line is found in code like this:

```
public static void Experiment1()
{
   for(int size = 5000; size <= 100000; size = size + 5000)
   {
     int[] a randomArray(size, 1000); //a random array of size 'size' and values from 1 - 1000
     a = sortFacade.sort(2, false, a);
     /** This is where the error occurs. 2 specifies insertion sort (error occurs 
      with other acceptable numbers here as well,false specifies descending
      order, 'a' specifies the array to be sorted.*/
   }
}
```

The SortFacade is a facade that interacts with all my different sorting algorithms. 2 is an acceptable value and calls to the same method (with different parameters) do work in other parts of the code.

Comment: can you add your code here? and what is sortFacade?

Comment: Post the exception here as well. Is it telling you that the method requires an int and is receiving a long? Or the other way around?

Comment: The literal `2` is an `int`, so you may be misinterpreting the message.  You should copy/paste the message directly from the IDE or terminal window.

Comment: Post the declaration of `a` and the definition of `sortFacade`.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE(http://sscce.org/) for better help.

Comment: `int[] a randomArray(size, 1000);` doesn't look like valid syntax...

Comment: Give the declaration of sortFacade.  That's the most important thing

Answer (score 1):

This basically talks for itself.

```
Experimenter.java:146: incompatible types
found   : long
required: int[]
```

You said yourself that the variable `a` is an array of integers. The above error tells you that although the method returns a `long`, you require it to return an array of integers `int[]`, because you try to assign that `long` value to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

if `a` is an `int[]` array, then it would seem that the error you are receiving is because `sortFacade.sort` has a return type of `long` and you are trying to assign it to the `a` array - which is illegal.

The reason `sortFacade.sort(2, false, a);` compiles is because you are not assigning it to anything. If you said: `long b = sortFacade.sort(2, false, a);` it should compile and work.